# loop that iterates through if statements where 3 separate indexes all change | all possible statements

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

TL/DR : Transferring if statements into a compact for loop that generates the if statements, problem was with changing the index. I solved it after completely writing the question :).

Hey everyone this is my first post. I am currently learning matlab, one of the tasks is to detect an isosceles triangle (Simple logic just to learn if statements, the code doesn't check if the side lengths are out of the bounds of a triangle). For my curiosity I have been trying to work out how I could use a for loop to generate the if statements, down below is the code that I want to change into a for loop.

```
    sideLength = [20 4 3]; %lengths of the sides
    
    if (sideLength(1) == sideLength(2)) && (sideLength(2) ~= sideLength(3)) %if side 1 and 2 are equal and 2 %does not equal 3
        disp('Isosceles');
        if (sideLength(2) == sideLength(3)) && (sideLength(3) ~= sideLength(1)) %if side 2 and 3 are equal %and side 3 does not equal 1
            disp('Isosceles');
            if (sideLength(3) == sideLength(1)) && (sideLength(1) ~= sideLength(2)) %if side 3 and 1 are %equal and side 1 does not equal side 2
                disp('Isosceles');
            end
        end
    end
```

**first iteration has to be if side(1) == side(2) and side(2) does not equal side(3)**

**second iteration   if side(2) == side(3) and side(3) does not equal side(1)**

**third iteration if side(3) == side (1) and side(1) does not equal side(2)**

I want to change that code ^ into a for loop that iterates through each if statement.
I have tried to work out how to keep the indices inside of the vector length while automatically changing.
Here is what I have tried so far.

```
    %vector with containing lengths of sides
    sideLength = [1 2 3];
    %This is to keep track of which if statement we are at
    ifStatement=["a" "b" "c"];
    
    for i=1:length(sideLength) %for loop that iterates 3 times
        %each iteration I want the if statement to change to create the same if
        %statements that are in the first set of code.
        
        %if statement below has been commented out for now
        %if sideLength(i) == sideLength(mod((i+1),(6-i))) %commented out this to use a print and work out
    
        fprintf('If statement %s equals if side(%d) == side(%d)\n', ifStatement(i), i, mod((i+1),(6-i)))
        %the mod((i+1),(6-i))) code equates to remainder of (1+1) / (6-1) = 2/5 = 2 (remainder), next 
        %iteration is remainder of (2 + 1) / (6-2) = 3/4 = 3 (remainder), last iteration = 1.
    end
```

This is the output of the code above.

```
    If statement a equals if side(1) == side(2)
    If statement b equals if side(2) == side(3)
    If statement c equals if side(3) == side(1)
```

I can't work out how to put the && statement and make it go

> If statement A equals if side(1) == side(2) and side(2) does not
> equal **side(3)**
>
> If statement B equals if side(2) == side(3) and
> side(3) does not equal **side(1)**
>
> If statement c equals if side(3) ==
> side(1) and side(1) does not equal **side(2)**

After spending a long time trying to work out the equation/all of these other possible super complicated ways of solving it and writing this post I worked out how to solve this. I understand that this may be simple to most of you but I will still post this and write how to solve this issue.
I would also like to note that I am currently learning python and matlab both at the same time, I started both of them 5 weeks ago during university. I was trying to transfer this modulo solution from python to matlab code which is where I was getting confused. I am going to post this with my answer in hopes of helping others learn.

Comment: writing helps cleaning up the mind ;)

Comment: One way to simplify the logic is to first see if all three values are equal. If not, then go into your three comparisons. Now these don't need the `&&` part, if two sides are equal it's guaranteed that the third one is different.

Comment: The next simplification involves sorting the `sideLength` array. After sorting, if `sideLength(1)== sideLength(3)`, all three sides are equal. Next, you only need to check two things: `sideLength(1)== sideLength(2)` and `sideLength(2)== sideLength(3)`. The third option no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem

```
    %vector with lengths
    sideLength = [1 2 3];
    %This is to keep track of which if statement we are at
    ifStatement=["a" "b" "c"];

    for i=1:length(sideLength) %for loop that iterates 3 times


        fprintf('If statement %s equals if (side(%d) == side(%d)) and (side(%d) ~= side(%d)) \n',...
            ifStatement(i), i, (mod((i),3)+1), (mod((i),3)+1), (mod((i+1),3)+1))
    end
```

This gives the output:

```
    If statement a equals if (side(1) == side(2)) and (side(2) ~= side(3)) 
    If statement b equals if (side(2) == side(3)) and (side(3) ~= side(1)) 
    If statement c equals if (side(3) == side(1)) and (side(1) ~= side(2))
```

The issue was in my understanding of mod. In Python indecies start at 0, in matlab they start at 1 and must go up in positive integers. I didn't really think I could do the mod operation and then add 1 to the answer to get around the issue of having a 0 as the index.

Originally I was trying to find a number that could have the index subtracted from it that when dividing the index by it would equal the pattern I wanted. The whole reason for this was to try and avoid having the index be something like 3/3 = 0 and then having an error.

The solution to this was to add 1 to the answer of the modulo functions result. This meant if the modulo answer was 0 then it would be turned into index(1).

```
    mod((i+1),(6-i))) %original attempt
    %iteration 1 = the remainder of (1+1) / (6-1) = (2)/(5) = remainder 2
    %iteration 2 = the remainder of (2+1) / (6-2) = (3)/(4) = remainder 3
    %iteration 3 = the remainder of (3+1) / (6-3) = (4)/(3) = remainder 1

    %The above was far too complicated when trying to use the same index number to solve     
    %for different patterns.

    %Below is the solution

    (mod((i),3)+1) %solved for middle part of if statement
    %iteration 1 = the remainder of (1/3) + 1 = 2
    %iteration 2 = the remainder of (2/3) + 1 = 3
    %iteration 3 = the remainder of (3/3) + 1 = 1
    %what solved this issue was understanding that I could put plus 1 outside of the mod 
    %operation to keep the indexes above 0 and solve the problem.


    %The last part of the if statement I wanted to give the pattern of 3, 1, 2.
    % to solve this I looked at (mod((i),3)+1). If I wanted to change that 
    %pattern from 2, 3, 1 I could simply add 1 at the point where the remainder was being 
    %calculated.
    (mod((i+1),3)+1) %solved for last part of if statement

    % pattern Iteration 1 (mod(1+1)/3) + 1 = (2) + 1 = 3
    % pattern Iteration 2 (mod(2+1)/3) + 1 = (0) + 1 = 1
    % pattern Iteration 3 (mod(3+1)/3) + 1 = (1) + 1 = 2
```

This is conceptualised as a clock. each number on the clock is the same when divide by the length of the clock and looking at the remainder.

```
    First hand on the clock will always  be 1. 1/3 = r.1 || 4/3 = r.1 || 7/3 = r.1 
    Second hand on the clock will always be 2. 2/3 = r.2 || 5/3 = r.2 || 8/3 = r.2
    Third hand on the clock will always  be 0. 3/3 = r.0 || 6/3 = r.0 || 9/3 = r.0
                  13
                  10
                  7
                  4  
                  1
    15, 12, 9, 6, 3 2, 5, 8, 11, 14
```

If I wanted to make a pattern of 1, 2 and 3, I had to add 1 to the answer of the above modulo equation so it had the range of 1 to 3.
Then work out which what to start the index with to get the desired pattern.

i.e pattern 2, 3, 1

```
    %iteration 1 = the remainder of (1/3) + 1 = 2
    %iteration 2 = the remainder of (2/3) + 1 = 3
    %iteration 3 = the remainder of (3/3) + 1 = 1
```

i.e pattern 3, 1, 2

```
    % pattern Iteration 1 (mod(1+1)/3) + 1 = (2) + 1 = 3
    % pattern Iteration 2 (mod(2+1)/3) + 1 = (0) + 1 = 1
    % pattern Iteration 3 (mod(3+1)/3) + 1 = (1) + 1 = 2
```

I hope this is a good explanation, it is a fairly simple problem when looked at like this but when I was trying to solve it by doing equations to work out the first method it was not simple.